# CSS 3 rows layout with the middle one going to right

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing a layout for mobile devices. And I have 3 blocks. The 1st and the 3rd blocks have some text fields, the 2nd block is filled by map. All my blocks do NOT look good when they are very wide. The browser window can have 2 types of orientation: book and album. I want to change blocks positions when the orientation is album. So, let me show how I see the blocks behaviour for these 2 orientations.

BOOK ORIENTATION:

```
+------------+
|   First    |
+------------+
|            |
|   Second   |
|            |
+------------+
|   Third    |
+------------+
```

HTML:

```
<div>First</div>
<div>Second</div>
<div>Third</div>
```

ALBUM ORIENTATION:

```
+------------+-------------+
|   First    |             |
+------------+    Second   |
|   Third    |             |
+------------+-------------+
```

How can I do it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: And where is your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I advice you to take a look at pure-css yahoo project at http://purecss.io/ and check out its grid part

Comment: The first configuration is the default, the second can be achieved using floats. http://jsfiddle.net/5dxmLg05/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

HTML:

```
<div>First</div>
<div class="right">Second</div>
<div>Third</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media all and (orientation: landscape) {
  div {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
  }
  .right {
     float: right;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a table you can put it in a div "div1" and use this jQuery event:

```
$( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) {
    if(event.orientation=="portrait") {
       $( "#div1" ).html("<table border="1"> <tr><td>First</td></tr> <tr><td>Second</td></tr> <tr><td>Third</td></tr></table>");
    }
    else if(event.orientation=="landscape") {
        $( "#div1" ).html("<table border="1"> <tr><td>First</td><td rowspan="2">Second</td></tr> <tr><td>Third</td></tr></table>");
    }
});
```

where the first case is:

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
       <td>First</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Second</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Third</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

which results:

```
+------------+
|   First    |
+------------+
|            |
|   Second   |
|            |
+------------+
|   Third    |
+------------+
```

and the second case is:

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
       <td>First</td>
       <td rowspan="2">Second</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Third</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

which results:

```
+------------+-------------+
|   First    |             |
+------------+    Second   |
|   Third    |             |
+------------+-------------+
```